# What this error means on Fail2ban?

Tags: fail2ban

I've installed fail2ban on my server. Anyway, I've seen this error on Fail2ban Log... What does it means?

Here's the error

```
2015-02-09 06:11:21,076 fail2ban.filter         [23563]: INFO    [apache-noscript] Found 218.76.103.111
2015-02-09 06:11:21,079 fail2ban.filter         [23563]: INFO    [apache-noscript] Found 218.76.103.111
2015-02-09 06:11:22,792 fail2ban.filter         [23563]: INFO    [apache-noscript] Found 218.76.103.111
2015-02-09 06:11:22,794 fail2ban.filter         [23563]: INFO    [apache-noscript] Found 218.76.103.111
2015-02-09 06:11:22,795 fail2ban.filter         [23563]: INFO    [apache-noscript] Found 218.76.103.111
2015-02-09 06:11:24,075 fail2ban.actions        [23563]: NOTICE  [apache-noscript] Ban 218.76.103.111
2015-02-09 06:11:24,414 fail2ban.action         [23563]: ERROR   iptables -n -L INPUT | grep -q 'f2b-apache-noscript[ \t]' -- stdout: ''
2015-02-09 06:11:24,415 fail2ban.action         [23563]: ERROR   iptables -n -L INPUT | grep -q 'f2b-apache-noscript[ \t]' -- stderr: ''
2015-02-09 06:11:24,463 fail2ban.action         [23563]: ERROR   iptables -n -L INPUT | grep -q 'f2b-apache-noscript[ \t]' -- returned 1
2015-02-09 06:11:24,463 fail2ban.CommandAction  [23563]: ERROR   Invariant check failed. Trying to restore a sane environment
2015-02-09 06:11:24,599 fail2ban.action         [23563]: ERROR   iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -j f2b-apache-noscript
iptables -F f2b-apache-noscript
iptables -X f2b-apache-noscript -- stdout: ''
2015-02-09 06:11:24,600 fail2ban.action         [23563]: ERROR   iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -j f2b-apache-noscript
iptables -F f2b-apache-noscript
iptables -X f2b-apache-noscript -- stderr: "iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load target `f2b-apache-noscript':No such file or directory\n\nTry `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.\niptables: No chain/target/match by that name.\niptables: No chain/target/match by that name.\n"
2015-02-09 06:11:24,600 fail2ban.action         [23563]: ERROR   iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -j f2b-apache-noscript
iptables -F f2b-apache-noscript
iptables -X f2b-apache-noscript -- returned 1
2015-02-09 06:11:24,600 fail2ban.actions        [23563]: ERROR   Failed to execute ban jail 'apache-noscript' action 'iptables-multiport' info 'CallingMap({'ipjailmatches': <function <lambda> at 0x7fdca67b6938>, 'matches': u'[Mon Feb 09 06:11:20.365794 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 30716] [client 218.76.103.111:4521] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php\n[Mon Feb 09 06:11:20.943914 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 30692] [client 218.76.103.111:4522] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php5\n[Mon Feb 09 06:11:21.553424 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 29940] [client 218.76.103.111:4523] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi\n[Mon Feb 09 06:11:22.125496 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 29770] [client 218.76.103.111:4524] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php.cgi\n[Mon Feb 09 06:11:22.693022 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 29907] [client 218.76.103.111:4525] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php4', 'ip': '218.76.103.111', 'ipmatches': <function <lambda> at 0x7fdca67b6a28>, 'ipfailures': <function <lambda> at 0x7fdca67b6aa0>, 'time': 1423458684.074246, 'failures': 5, 'ipjailfailures': <function <lambda> at 0x7fdca67b69b0>})': Error stopping action
```

Comment: Exactly what sort of server is this?

Comment: Is it a VPS from OVH